# cocos2dx save image in to gallery android

Tags: android, bitmap, cocos2d-x-2.x

I want to take screenshots and save it in the gallery.
What I have tried:

```
CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

CCRenderTexture* texture = CCRenderTexture::create((int)size.width, (int)size.height, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888);
texture->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
texture->begin();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit();
texture->end();
texture->saveToFile("scrshot.png", kCCImageFormatJPEG);
```

in iOS it is working perfectly and am able to save image in to documents, but the problem is in android :

There are two possibilities

1)   texture->saveToFile("scrshot.png", kCCImageFormatJPEG); or  texture->saveToFile("My path"); -> It compiles but where is the image saved?

2)   Use JNI to save Bitmap file -> problem is how to cast CCRenderTexture to Bitmap and parse it.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this issue quickly but forgot to give the answer but now giving because it may help someone

My code is only for iOS and android

code is

```
CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

CCRenderTexture* texture = CCRenderTexture::create((int)size.width, (int)size.height, kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888);
texture->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
texture->begin();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit();
texture->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)

    std::string str =  CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
    str.append("/imageNameToSave.png");
    const char * c = str.c_str();
    texture->saveToFile(c);
    SaveImageAndroidJNI(true);

#else

        texture->saveToFile("imageNameToSave.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
        BridgeClass::shared()->saveTOAlbum();

#endif
```

In My BridgeClass

```
void BridgeClass:: saveTOAlbum(){

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *yourArtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/imageNameToSave.png"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourArtPath];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert !" message:@"Photo Saved To Photos." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

For iOS it will save to gallery

For android there is a class androidJNI.cpp

```
void SaveImageAndroidJNI(bool visible){
        JniMethodInfo t;
        if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, "yourPackageName/ClassName"
                                           ,"SaveImageAndroidJNI"
                                           ,"(Z)V"))
        {
            t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID,t.methodID,visible);
        }
    }
```

And android native method for save image to data/data

```
static void SaveImageAndroidJNI(final boolean visible)
{

    ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(me);
    String path = c.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/imageNameToSave.png";
    System.out.println("Paht to check --"+path);
    File imgFile = new  File(path);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    uris.add(Uri.parse(path));

    OutputStream output;
 // Find the SD Card path
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Your Folder Name/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, "imageNameToSave.png");

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");

        me.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));    
}
```

when access this image from data/data will not accessible directly here save this image to sd card and the access it from cocos2dx

but for android have to get writable path using getWritablePath function and parse this value to saveToFile function and the `SaveImageAdmobJNI(true);` will call native method ,in native method you can save take the image path and save it to gallery

**Note:** getWritablePath() - this function will give you the path from data->data->YOUR_PAKAGE

Feel free to ask queries.

Comment: Is BridgeClass an inbuilt class or you have made it. I can't get any bridgeClass in cocos2d-x

Comment: I have created that bridgeClass.

Comment: i need to get that save to album method. Can i get this particular method please.

Comment: Check my edited answer, if any problem feel free to ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69815/discussion-between-anjdenny-and-umesh-sharma).

Comment: Code is not working on newer android OS anyone has solution ?