# Passing Image from ios/c++ code to JNI Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, byte, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to provide a feature for the user to save a screenshot of the current screen.
I am using cocos2d-x v3.0 and c++, and am implementing this feature for the first time.
I did some googling and found this piece of code

> This Code Work Perfectly for store image in ios photos

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                  [NSString stringWithUTF8String: filename] ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

> I think byte array may resolve my problem but i don't know how to transfer this image to android via jni method/byte array

**Some more code snippet**

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)

std::string str =  CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
str.append("/imageNameToSave.png");
const char * c = str.c_str();
tex->saveToFile(c);

this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(Dressup_screen_BG_button_view::Photo_Save_Gallery_Android),1.0);

#else

tex->saveToFile("imageNameToSave.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
 this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(Dressup_screen_BG_button_view::Photo_Save_Gallery),1.0);
#endif


// This is native method which will save photo 
-( void )ThisPhotoClick{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourArtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/imageNameToSave.png"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourArtPath];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert !" message:@"Photo Saved To Photos." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];}
```

**Android Method**

```
public  static void SaveImageAndroidJNI(final boolean visible)
{

    ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(me);
    String path = c.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/imageNameToSave.png";
    System.out.println("Paht to check --"+path);
    File imgFile = new File(path);

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    uris.add(Uri.parse(path));

    OutputStream output;
    // Find the SD Card path



    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Your Folder Name/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, "imageNameToSave.png");

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");

    me.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
}
```

**Note**

> getWritablePath(); Now not working due to runtime permission issue, I already try to ask for permission at start of android app but still not working so don't suggest me to do this

**I Want to save captured image in my android device but i can't find way**

[My implementation is reference from this question but it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24078695/3514144)

**Debug**

[image]

Returns null as bitmap i tried with several methods to decode bitmap,When i put it on try block it shows me [open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22435061/3514144)

**I observe there is no png in data/data/package so i said getWritable path not working for android**

Here is my [conversation](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cant-see-any-so-file-in-my-jnilibs/46901/19?u=freebabygames) with Cocos Community Evangelist

Any help much appreciable

Answer (score 1):

For the Android Side:

I don't see any Manifest code but this is required for path creation.  Place under `<application>` tag before the `</application>`:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.cognizant.expressprescriptionregistration.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**Also, if you are using Android SDK 29 add this to your Manifest as well and within the** `<application` **tag**

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**Under folder res > layout > xml 
add "file_paths.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="any text you want here"
        path="Pictures/"/>
</paths>
```

**And the Java code for setting where to store the image**

```
// Create the file where the photo will be stored
    private File createPhotoFile() {

        // Name of file
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        // Location of storage
        File storedDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File photo = null;

        try {

            // Creates file in storedDir
            photo = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storedDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add that things on my question but i already try this i mean using of file providers